# Programmatically turn off a non-jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

If it is possible is it possible for iOS devices or just some? If so, which ones. If so, are there any resources / documentation where I find out more explicitly?

Comment: I'm sure everyone would totally love for random apps to be turning the phone off when they least expect it...

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible for apps to programmatically turn off the iPhone

**No.** There's no public API in iOS 9 (or any previous version) for switching the phone off.

> are there any resources / documentation where I find out more explicitly?

The primary source for information like this is [Apple's iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer no. Longer answer, still no.